Force column to appear when no data returned for group after summarising dataframe
I have a (non-shareable) data frame of cases of disease (each row is a person with a disease) and columns corresponding to their age group (Age_Grp_15) and their quintile of marginalization (AGE_LABOURFORCE_Q_CSDUID).
I want to create a summary table of case counts based on age and marginalization. So far, I have:
count_age <- marg_data_1920 %>%
  group_by(Age_Grp_15, AGE_LABOURFORCE_Q_CSDUID) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  spread(AGE_LABOURFORCE_Q_CSDUID, count, fill = 0)

Here is something I have done successfully with the same code. All cells fill with numbers as they should:

However, my disease dataframe does not have any cases in my first quintile:

I want to force R to list the first quintile column and fill it with zeroes in cases when there is no data.
I have tried the code below, which has not worked:
count_age <- marg_data_1920 %>%
  group_by(Age_Grp_15, AGE_LABOURFORCE_Q_CSDUID) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  complete(Age_Grp_15, nesting(AGE_LABOURFORCE_Q_CSDUID), fill = list(count = 0)) %>%
  spread(AGE_LABOURFORCE_Q_CSDUID, count, fill = 0) %>%
  rename(age = Age_Grp_15)

colnames(count_age) <- c("age", "q_1","q_2","q_3","q_4","q_5")


Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are more likely to get help here if you share a reproducible example of your problem, and that includes code and sample data. Since your data is private, create a sample of it and add it to your question so that other developers can replicate the problem and offer solutions.

I can only provide a general answer unless you update your question with a reproducible example, as others have mentioned in the comments. Using the mtcars data, you have to turn the column into factor. Otherwise, if it isn't present in your data how else would R knows that level exists?
In this example, there is no car with 100 cylinders (that I know of), but we can still include it in our count like so:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mtcars |>
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(unique(cyl), 100))) |>
  count(cyl, .drop = FALSE) |> # <- .drop = FALSE: include counts for empty groups
  pivot_wider(names_from = "cyl", values_from = "n")
# # A tibble: 1 × 4
#     `6`   `4`   `8` `100`
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1     7    11    14     0

